# Switching between Server and Client

Tags: 12.04, server

I am pretty new to ubuntu.I know that on installing ubuntu server i can install desktop version or GUI on it.My Questions are following.

1. Will that new GUI will now act as server or client?
2. If yes then how to switch between the two?

if i am wrong then please guide me how to have both server and desktop versions on the same machine or what is the best practice?

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server or Client; it is all about installed packages :)

from your server installation; you can run `tasksel` and install Desktop componnt(S)

if not installed, Open Terminal and run `sudo apt-get install tasksel`

This will install **tasksel** which is a Debian/Ubuntu tool that installs multiple related packages as a co-ordinated "task" onto your system`

you can then run `sudo tasksel`and you will see a list of common installable server and Desktop components e.g

- Basic Ubuntu Server
- OpenSSH Server
- LAMP Server
- Mail Server
- kubuntu Desktop
- Lubuntu Desktop
- Ubuntu Desktop
- PostgreSQL Database
- Samba file server.... and much else

For the switch; there is no actual switch to turn on or off :); but you will usually connect to a Server via a remote SSH terminal (putty for example)

when you want to connect to Desktop (GUI), you may login locally or remotely via VNC (or RDP after installing xrdp package)

For best practice; **you don't need to install GUI on a Server**.

But if you do need to, here is the simplest words as I see **install only what need to have on a Server box**, and DON'T install *ubuntu Desktop components as it will install too many packages you don't actually need.

if you need a GUI; install `Lubuntu Minimal Installation` from `tasksel`

if you will login locally, you can choose between the Desktop environment (GUI) of shell environment (command line)

simplest way is to press `Alt+Ctrl+F1` to bring you to tty1 (ttys 1 through 6 are command line and tty7 is for GUI) and after the first `Alt+Ctrl+F1`,

you can switch between them with only `Alt+F#` according to the required terminal #

P.S: tty stands for a terminal

hope this helps you (if so; don't forget an upvote and mark as an answer :D )

Comment: Thanks very much. But i did not understand how would i switch between the two if i connect locally.please a little bit elaborate.

Comment: if you will login locally, you can choose between the Desktop environment (GUI) of shell environment (command line)...........simplest way is to press Alt+Ctrl+F1 to bring you to tty1 (ttys 1 through 6 are command line and tty7 is for GUI) and after the first Alt+Ctrl+F1, you can swtch between them with only Alt+F# according to the required terminal 
P.S: tty stands for a terminal

Comment: @khan I moved it to the original answer for better formatting and readability.

Comment: I have the suspect that @khan still thinks that server and desktop are two different machines... and no, this is not the case. If you install client and desktop on a machine, you will have ONE machine that has all the programs that makes it a Server **plus** all the software that makes it a Desktop. Virtual console login is not different from graphical login and using a terminal window. Ahmadgeo, maybe you should clarify this more in your answer.